# How to find the pair in an array which have maximum gcd

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have to find the the pair in an array which have maximum GCD. I tried different approach but all those solution doesn't run in time, time limit exceed in every solution.

So is there any efficient method to do so.

example =>

```
Input : arr[] : { 1 2 3 4 5 }
Output : 2
```

Explanation : Pair {2, 4} has GCD 2 which is highest. Other pairs have a GCD of 1.

I tried these solutions =>

- brute force
- brute force with Euclidean algorithm
- By calculating the frequency of all the divisors of each number present in
  the array. And then check which divisor have the frequency greater than 1
  from last. (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-pair-maximum-gcd-array)

All above mentioned solution doesn't work.

The link to the question is
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-gcd-pair3534/1

Comment: "I tried different approach" -- you need to say exactly what you've already tried, otherwise someone suggesting a solution could be wasting their time.

Comment: @j_random_hacker please check again the question. I updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the same logic, divisor occurrence but with a simple optimization. Instead of calculating divisor for each number separately. We will calculate divisors collectively and calculate the answer accordingly. We will traverse each number and then it all multiple till max_element and will keep track of the number of elements for which the current number is the divisor and if the occurrence is greater than 1 we will update our answer. So the solution will be,

```
int MaxGcd(int n, int a[]) { 
        
    int mx = *max_element(a, a + n);
    
    vector<int> cnt(mx + 1, 0);
    vector<int> occurrence(mx + 1, 0);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        occurrence[a[i]]++;
    }
    
    int ans = 1;
    
    for (int i = 2; i <= mx; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j <= mx; j += i) {
            cnt[i] += occurrence[j];
            if (cnt[i] > 1) {
                ans = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain me your solution. I didn't get it.

Comment: Added in the answer. Just dry run once you will get the idea. It is a simple one.